# Android: VelocityTracker Couldn't open '/dev/touch' (Permission denied)

Tags: android, touch, permission-denied, floating-action-button

Well, I have this problem for some time now, and I think its getting a little annoying... A used the FloatingActionButton from Clans (https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton) and for some reason after touching the FloatingActionMenu and try to touch the FloatingActionButton the error below is shown in my logcat. I already tested in another devicess (BQ Aquaris, NEXUS 5 and HUAWEI P8) and always get the same message. After the first touch in the FloatingActionButton all others touch even and the same FloatingActionButton start to work normally, just in the first I get this message...

What can be? Anyone had this error?

```
12:06:14.916    4760    test    INFO    View    Touch down dispatch to android.widget.ImageView{42305d38 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-320,547 #7f060016 app:id/imageView}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=132.7305, y[0]=411.52383, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=2697993, downTime=2697993, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
12:06:14.919    4760    test    INFO    View    Touch down dispatch to com.github.clans.fab.Label{42300ce0 V.ED..C. ......I. 63,392-199,419}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=69.7305, y[0]=19.523834, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=2697993, downTime=2697993, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
12:06:14.920    4760    test    DEBUG   VelocityTracker Couldn't open '/dev/touch' (Permission denied)
12:06:14.920    4760    test    DEBUG   VelocityTracker tpd read x fail: Bad file number
12:06:14.920    4760    test    DEBUG   VelocityTracker tpd read y fail: Bad file number
12:06:14.978    4760    test    INFO    View    Touch up dispatch to com.github.clans.fab.Label{42300ce0 V.ED..C. ...p..I. 63,392-199,419}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=69.7305, y[0]=19.523834, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=2698055, downTime=2697993, deviceId=3, source=0x1002 }
```

Code:

```
fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.capture);
fabCapturar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
         fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
         {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v)
              {
                  Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
                  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                        startActivityForResult(i, _Photo);
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
              }
          });
    }
```

});

I don't have any idea in how to resolve this error... and the google don't want to help!

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Bring fab to front of all views try this
`fab.bringToFront();`